# Why does こっそり not use the particle に?

Tags: grammar, particles, adverbs

I am reading Disney's Aladdin to learn Japanese. Here is a portion at the start:

> 馬に乗って2人の男が、アラビアの砂漠のはずれで、約束の時間に、こっそりとあいました。

Two questions:

1. Just to confirm, はずれ means "on the outskirts", right? So they are meeting on the outskirts of the Arabian desert?
2. What is こっそりと？ I am suspecting it means "secretly" (こっそり)。But "secretly" being an adverb, why does it not use the particle "に", as in こっそりにあいました？

Answer (score 1, accepted):

meeting on the outskirts of the Arabian desert? --> Yes.

こっそりと - ‎secretly, surreptitiously, ...

---

re: -と versus -に -- I did some searching but can't find a page explaining it (except for the one in the comment).

1. [Noun]に --- 静かに ・ 端的に ・ 単刀直入に ・ 率直に ・ ストレートに · ....... when [Noun]だ is a 形容動詞 e.g. 「静かだ」「親切だ」
2. [onomatopoeia]と ---   はっきり(と), ハキハキ(と),　・　ズバリ(と), ズバズバ(と),　・　ひっそり(と), ひそひそ(と),　・　こっそり(と), こそこそ(と),　. . .

With some [onomatopoeia] both cases are possible :

- [onomatopoeia]と -- 「星がピカピカと光る」　ピカピカ(と), ピカリ(と) -- ( usual description pattern / modifying the verb. )
- [onomatopoeia]に -- 「床をピカピカに磨く」-- the meaning is similar to 「床をピカピカに ( なるように / なるまで ) 磨く」

... 解凍時にべたべたになってしまった餃子の皮で ... フライパンにサラダ油を入れて餃子の皮をパリパリになるまで炒める。 --> パリパリになった餃子の皮

ジーパンを洗濯すると硬くてゴワゴワになるのですが ... うちの場合はゴワゴワになったタオルは掃除用になります） フワフワにするとなると必然 ...